# Find hiddenfield by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

**Hi,**

How do I find a hidden field by value(not id)? I known that I can get value by the following :

```
$('#MyHiddenField').val();
```

But In this case I need to find the field by val and then clear it.

**Pleas help!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$('input:hidden[value="..."]')
```

Comment: You can also use other attribute selectors, such as _contains_ or _ends-with_.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == $whatever) $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: doh. This works but Slaks is a lot better. Dunno why I failed to think of that :/